# What do I do if my puppy's splint keeps slipping off?

Tags: dogs, health, injury

I have a 4 week old foster puppy with a broken Tibia and his splint/cast has slipped off twice. He doesn't move or anything he just sleeps and it comes off. The vet at the shelter don't know what to do and are thinking of amputating his leg. What do we do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have they tried placing a cast instead? Maybe they need a different technique or stickier tape. Hard to say as I'm not sure how it was done originally.

If you're willing to spend some money (well, a lot of money) or if the shelter is, you can go see a veterinary orthopedic surgeon for an alternative to amputation. They would have better knowledge and equipment to deal with this situation.

Some rescues will do fund raisers for these special cases, you could even offer to help the shelter do one.

Good luck to your little one, I hope you can find another option besides amputation.